Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp when executing a script
I just need some help. I have been using this script, however today I got this error. I have not change anything and it works perfectly fine until today.
function createPMA() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var destinationfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1o_OlGBT-THhhyduVL34jgnG0T4slB-n6");
  var lobname =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Audience").getRange("L6").getValue(); 

When executing this, a form will be created.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.
